# Is it legal for voters to take age of candidate into consideration?

Tags: united-states, voting, politics

Some times in conversations that a candidate is too young/old. I wonder as it is illegal for companies to discriminate on basis of race/age/gender etc.

So will it be illegal for voters to think/decide on these factors?

If it is illegal, how it can be proved?

Comment: I don't know how you could enforce this, considering the ballot is secret - you don't have to tell anyone *who* you voted for, let alone the reason...

Comment: One could make the perhaps provocative argument that elections are meant to be discriminatory: It is likely that voters will feel their interests best represented by officials like themselves. The race, skin color, religion, sexual orientation, age or pregnancy status they have themselves are likely major criteria in their decisions (counter-examples notwithstanding ;-) ). The overall election result will tend to be a mirror image of the society (e.g. it would be strange to have a U.S. government of mostly white men ... oh wait ...).

Comment: Are you aware that the US constitution explicitly requires a candidate for president be at least 35 and that their nation of birth is the US?

Comment: I have to say this is a fascinating question, and applicable to Canada as well (caveat nuances/differences in our laws).

Comment: If it would be illegal for voters to vote for any candidate of their choice, the voting would be a mockery. Such things happen only in some exotic dictatures.

Comment: Why not please read what Mindwin wrote?

After that, what jurisdiction are you Asking about? US or UK or where?

It's legal for voters to consider anything about a candidate; more legal even than anything they might otherwise say against that candidate.

That works in the same way it's legal to consider the candidate's height or weight, skin colour or anything else…

Comment: I've read that many people say they would never again vote for "that old orange orangutan".  I don't think that violates any laws in their jurisdictions even though it exemplifies bias against age, color, and species.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Not quite - they have to be a citizen from birth, but this does _not_ necessarily require them to have been born in the U.S. (having at least one U.S.-citizen parent is enough, as is birth in most unincorporated U.S. territories or aboard a U.S.-registered aircraft or ship).

Comment: @Vikki You are right; sloppiness on my my part.  Thanks for clarrifying.

Answer (score 65):

### Discrimination in employment

The starting point is: discrimination is legal unless there is a law that says it isn't.

So for example, when I advertise a plumbing position, I can discriminate on the basis of if a candidate is or is not a plumber and, further, I can discriminate on how good a plumber I think they are.

What I can't do, in the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states) is discriminate against someone on the basis of age *if* they are 40 or older. It is legal for me to discriminate against someone on age if they are younger than 40. Why? Because that's what the law says.

The full list of what constitutes illegal discrimination in employment is a person's race, color, religion, sex (including gender identity, sexual orientation, and pregnancy), national origin, age (40 or older), disability or genetic information. It is also illegal to retaliate against a person because he or she complained about discrimination, filed a charge of discrimination, or participated in an employment discrimination investigation or lawsuit.

### Elections aren't employment

Voters are free to vote for the candidate of their choice based on whatever reason they want. If I want to decide that the only candidates I will vote for are female homosexuals between the ages of 27 and 62 with one leg and a pirate accent, then that's my right.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133941/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-is-it-legal-for-voters-to-take-age-of-candidate-i).

Comment: There are lots of other kinds of discrimination that aren't illegal and not employment (e.g. housing, public accommodations, public services), but elections aren't one of them.

Comment: @ohwilleke: As I understand, the argument is that while they can't discriminate on who can try to **run** for an election (Provided they meet minimum requirements to run for an election), they *can* discriminate on who they will vote for, effectively preventing certain candidates from winning elections, if they can convince enough people to not vote for them.

Comment: I cannot make logical sense of the paragraph *"What I can't do, in the united-states is discriminate on the basis of age if they are 40 or older. It is legal for me to discriminate on age if they are younger than 40. Why? Because that's what the law says."* What could this possibly mean? If I have to choose between two plumbers, Alfred who is younger than 40, and Bob who is older than 40, then I am allowed to choose Alfred on the basis that Alfred is younger, but I'm not allowed to choose Alfred on the basis that Bob is older?

Comment: @Stef You can discriminate against Alfred on the basis of age. You cannot discriminate against Bob on the basis of age. You can choose the better plumber and not consider age.

Comment: @Stef I think you should interpret it as it's illegal to disadvantage someone over 40 due to age discrimination, but not to disadvantage someone under 40. It is typically the person being disadvantaged by discrimination that is described as being discriminated.

Comment: What constitutes illegal discrimination in employment in the United States derives from a combination of federal and state law; there is no "full list" applicable in every state.

Comment: Reading your last sentence, I'm wondering if you might not have stumbled on the **real** reason voting is down. "I mean she *seems* OK, but a limp is still 2 legs, and that is really more of a Bristol accent. Guess I'm not voting again."

Comment: @Stef and others: It's important to note here that the entire first section is about *employment* - if I own a plumbing business and am filling a position at my business with one of these two people, I can't use their age as a deciding factor. If I as a *homeowner* am looking for a plumber to fix a sink, I may freely discriminate on any criteria I choose.

Answer (score 5):

> So will it be illegal for voters to think/decide on these factors?

> If it is illegal, how it can be proved?

Take in consideration:

1. The [burden of proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(law)) is on the accuser. To press criminal charges against anyone, the prosecution must prove beyond reasonable doubt that a crime happened. With hard evidence.
2. in the USA, [ballots are secret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_ballot). There's no way to prove how a specific voter voted.
3. In the USA, a person is protected against [self-incrimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-incrimination) by the Fifth Amendment.
4. Forcing to reveal how a particular person voted can lead to **Vote-Buying**, a kind of [electoral fraud](https://ballotpedia.org/Electoral_fraud). It is in all parties interest to make sure vote secrecy stands.

A rational voter could vote any way they wanted. Even if voting for reason X or Y was a crime, unless they gave up their Fifth Amendment rights (and a reasonable person wouldn't as it brings them no benefits), it is impossible to prosecute such a case.

By (4) we can see that even trying to collect evidence on how a person voted, reasons notwithstanding, is a felony.

So, no. It is not illegal to use any criteria to cast a ballot because it is impossible to prosecute, even if a law against it existed. It doesn't but we won't attempt to prove a negative for obvious reasons.

Now, if the voter is not rational and goes on social media or any other public forum and brag they didn't vote for X because X has the Y protected characteristic (be it age, gender, ethnical group, disability, religion, etc), they could be liable for libel based on their statments, but not the vote.

Comment: More fundamentally, voters are never under any obligation to vote for any particular candidate, and have the absolute right to withhold their vote from any candidate for any reason they see fit.  While some acts may be unlawful but unprosecutable, there is nothing even remotely unlawful about voting against a candidate because of sex, age, race, religion, or membership in some other "protected class", just as they would be free to vote against a candidate because he has green eyes.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for your assertion that it would be libel to announce you voted against someone because of a protected characteristic?  I'm very sceptical about this claim.

Comment: Libel is a *false* statement about someone that damages their reputation, and I doubt making false statements about any of the protected characteristic would be likely to damage reputation much. Also, saying that that was the reason you did/didn't vote for them has no bearing on the situation.

Comment: This doesn't hold water. Employment discrimination works the same way - there's no way to prove *why* someone was/wasn't hired unless the discriminator confesses - and yet employment discrimination is *clearly* illegal and gets litigated all the time. Discrimination by voters *is* legal, but the reason has nothing to do with the difficulty of enforcement.

Comment: @Robert "there's no way to prove why someone was/wasn't hired unless the discriminator confesses" Not true. Most cases are proven by circumstantial evidence and credibility determinations.

Comment: *3. A person is protected against self-incrimination* The protection prevents the person being punished by not self-incriminating, but it does not forbid the person voluntarily self-incriminating. Otherwise no confession or even guilty plea would be valid.

Comment: @SJuan76 that's why we assume a rational person, who wouldn't confess or plea guilty if the prosecution doesn'

Comment: @AlanDev "could" is the keyword. It's not a hard afffirmation. One could think that a public statement on social media might become basis for a lawsuit.

Comment: _It is not illegal to use any criteria to cast a ballot because it is impossible to prosecute, even if a law against it existed._  
This is not correct, I believe. A law against discrimination does exist, and AFAIK, doesn't have an exception for elections. Thus It is illegal to vote-with-discrimination, it's just *exceedingly* difficult to prosecute. Which isn't the same as "not illegal" because there exists windows where self-incrimination is in the rational person's best interest.

Comment: @Mindwin If you haven't seen https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0315983/ I suggest you do

Comment: @studog In the US at least, there is no general prohibition on discrimination, and I've never heard of a criminal discrimination statute.  It's not illegal for a person to refuse to associate with another because of their race or gender, except in specific cases like a business refusing service (and then it would be a civil issue, not a criminal one).  There are crimes where the sentence can be increased on the basis that it was a "hate crime," but as far as I know there aren't crimes which require proving prohibited discrimination.

Comment: @Mindwin - you can think what you like but I was looking for evidence :-)

Comment: The Fifth Amendment doesn't apply to civil lawsuits. Part of the corporate personhood that leftists hate so much is that they can be subpoenaed and be held in contempt if they refuse to comply with discovery.

Comment: One of the Wikipedia articles you link specifically mentions exceptions to secret ballot in the US. Seems that in some cases it would be *technically possible* to link a vote to a voter, and it wouldn't be particularly anti-constitutional to do so.

Comment: @Robert: "there's no way to prove *why* someone was/wasn't hired" - but that's not the question. For employment discrimination, the basis is that someone was not hired by a given employer, and then, as explained in other comments, circumstantial evidence can be used to determine whether that happened due to illegal discrimination. In secret elections, on the other hand, there is no way to prove whether or not someone was or wasn't voted for by a given voter in the first place.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Determining whether someone wasn't hired due to illegal discrimination IS asking why they weren't hired. It's a lot easier to determine whether a government official was elected for race or whatever than if a given employee was. But there's a big difference in culpability between a single HR person not hiring 15 hispanic people than a million people not voting for one official.

Comment: @MichaelS: That's all beside the point. The question is not *why* they were not hired/voted for, but *whether* they were not hired/voted for at all. That question is perfectly answerable in an employment situation, but, by virtue of secret ballots, intentionally unanswerable in an election. More concisely: You can tell whether employer X hired applicant Y. But you **cannot** tell whether voter X voted for candidate Y.